# Parsing xml with namespace in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, xml-parsing

I have an xml data coming with namespaces as shown below.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns1:report ns1:version="1.2" ns1:type="TRANSACTIONAL" xmlns:ns1="http://www.report/1.2">
  <ns1:entities>
    <ns1:entity ns1:type="PHYSICIANS">
      <ns1:entity ns1:instance="207" ns1:type="PHYSICIAN" ns1:id="P1">
        <ns1:attribute ns1:name="ID">207</ns1:attribute>
        <ns1:attribute ns1:name="NAME">Dr. George</ns1:attribute>
        <ns1:attribute ns1:name="ADDRESS_LINE_1">903 Lake Otis pkway </ns1:attribute>
        <ns1:attribute ns1:name="ADDRESS_LINE_2" />
        <ns1:attribute ns1:name="COUNTRY" ns1:tc="1" ns1:code="OLI_NATION_USA">United States of America</ns1:attribute>
        <ns1:attribute ns1:name="STATE" ns1:tc="2" ns1:code="OLI_USA_AK">Alaska</ns1:attribute>
        <ns1:attribute ns1:name="CITY">Anchorage</ns1:attribute>
      </ns1:entity>
      <ns1:entity ns1:instance="208" ns1:type="PHYSICIAN" ns1:id="P2">
        <ns1:attribute ns1:name="ID">208</ns1:attribute>
        <ns1:attribute ns1:name="NAME">Dr. James Hanover</ns1:attribute>
        <ns1:attribute ns1:name="ADDRESS_LINE_1">220 Plano pkway </ns1:attribute>
        <ns1:attribute ns1:name="ADDRESS_LINE_2" />
        <ns1:attribute ns1:name="COUNTRY" ns1:tc="1" ns1:code="OLI_NATION_USA">United States of America</ns1:attribute>
        <ns1:attribute ns1:name="STATE" ns1:tc="2" ns1:code="OLI_USA_AK">Texas</ns1:attribute>
        <ns1:attribute ns1:name="CITY">Dallas</ns1:attribute>
      </ns1:entity> 
    </ns1:entity>
  </ns1:entities>
</ns1:report>
```

I want this to be parsed and flattened to get an output as below to load to a table.

```html
|ID    |NAME                |ADDRESS_LINE_1  |ADDRESS_LINE_2   |COUNTRY                 |STATE  |CITY      |
|----  |------------------  |--------------------|-----------------|----------------------------|------ |----------|
|207   |Dr. George      |903 Lake Otis pkway |null             |United States of America    |Alaska |Anchorage |
|208   |Dr. James Hanover   |220 Plano pkway     |null             |United States of America    |Texas  |Dallas    |
```

I have tried using the spark-xml but unable to bring it to a table like structure.

This is what I have tried so far.

```html
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode

df = (spark.read 
    .format("com.databricks.spark.xml") 
    .option("rootTag", "ns1:entities") 
    .option("rowTag", "ns1:entity") 
    .load("/data/test/abc.xml"))

df_expl = df.select(
        '*',
        explode("`ns1:entity`").alias('N')
    )

df_expl2 = df_expl.select(explode("N.ns1:attribute").alias("M"))
```

I am not able to map the names to corresponding values as it is coming as different attributes with this.

Can anyone help me with this issue ?